# writing multiple alarms, alarm manager overrides them?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm extremely confused as to why when I first set an alarm it goes off, then i try to set it again and it doesn't. BUT the THIRD time it works, and so does the 5th,7th,9th etc... so every 2 times i set the alarm it works. I'm thoroughly confused because I gave my pending intent a uniqID specifically so this doesn't happen but maybe somewhere else I messed up..?

```
setAlarm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); 

                myCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, datePicker.getYear());
                myCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, datePicker.getMonth());
                myCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
                myCal.set(Calendar.HOUR, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
                myCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
                myCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

                //precaution if the user restarts their phone. Saves the alarm to a file
                //and when user restarts their phone register a broadcast receiver to pick up
                //the broadcast and then re-create the alarms that were stored. 
                setAlarms(datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth()
                        , timePicker.getCurrentHour(), timePicker.getCurrentMinute(), assignmentName);

                Intent triggered = new Intent(ManageAlarms.this, alarms.DisplayNotification.class);
                triggered.putExtra("NotificationId", 1);
                triggered.putExtra("assignmentName", assignmentName);

                PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        ManageAlarms.this, counter, triggered, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

                /*boolean alarmActive = (PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0,
                        triggered, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);

                if (alarmActive) {
                    alarmManager.cancel(displayIntent);
                }*/

                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                        myCal.getTimeInMillis(), displayIntent);
                counter++;
```

Comment: How do You set the alarms and what is Your intention? Is it possible that You set the next alarm to close to the last? For example, Alarm is executed at eight a clock, then is closed at one second after eight, then Your alarm is set directly to the next second after stop.

Comment: Use `adb shell dumpsys alarm` to confirm that your events are being scheduled for the times you think they should be.

Comment: ultimately I want the user to be able to set as many alarms as they want. One of the features of the app is to be able to set alarms for assignments someone might have in their classes. And I don't think it has anything to do with how close I set the alarms. If I set an alarm now and then wait 5 minutes to set the next one, it makes no difference, it doesn't go off. The one after that will though. 
Thanks CommonsWare, I checked that out and I see my alarms being scheduled...but it doesn't give me any explanation as to why only every other alarm is being fired...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, the Pending Intent in "Alarm Set" should be a Broadcast Receiver([See here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)).  I recommend the following:

Replace

```
PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        ManageAlarms.this, counter, triggered, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

with

```
PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        ManageAlarms.this, counter, triggered, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

The DisplayNotification class should extend BroadcastReceiver and implement onReceive().

Comment: nope :/ 
When I do it that way it doesn't get to onReceive. not sure why but meh...

Comment: ok for some unknown reason... I erased the changes I made to try the getBroadcast method and now it works perfectly...speechless. Sometimes android baffles me. I'm going to accept your answer just because :D

Comment: BTW, on the original issue you faced, I tried a little bit in a similar scenario.  Since you are not using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP, each alarm expiry will create one new instance of same activity.  In this scenario,  discovered that at a time only two instances were active on my emulator (and 3 in by galaxy S3).  The other instances (assuming we have more alarm expiries meanwhile) would only activate (ie., onCreate called) when I start closing the current active instances.  One thing that surprised me, order of activities creation did not match order of alarm expiry